# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child for HTML Form

Tags: object, reactjs

I wrote a function to build an HTML form based on the keys and values of an object and I am trying to return the form in my `render` method. However, I keep getting the error:

`ReactJs 0.14 - Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child`

Here is my `createForm()` method:

```
  createForm() {

    const obj = {

    }

    const object_fields = resourceFields.fields;
    let form = document.createElement('form');

    _.forIn(object_fields, function(field_value, field_name) {


        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('className', 'form-control');

        let label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute('htmlFor', 'name');
        label.innerHTML = field_name;

        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('className', 'form-control');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input.setAttribute('ref', field_name);
        input.setAttribute('id', field_name);
        input.setAttribute('value', field_value);
        input.setAttribute('onChange', '{this.handleChange}');

        div.appendChild(label);
        div.appendChild(input);
        form.appendChild(div);

    })

    console.log(form) //this prints out fine

    return form


  }
```

Here is my `render()` method:

```
render() {
  return (
      <div>
        {this.createForm()}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Does anyone know what might be happening? My form prints out in the console just fine... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never manipulate actual DOM nodes when you're working with React. When you build your UI in the `render` function, the JSX markup is translated into plain JavaScript (`React.createElement` function calls), which builds a **representation** of the DOM.

So, in your case, you should return JSX in `createForm`, not a DOM element.